# Access localhost port remotely

Tags: localhost, remote-server

I am trying to set up Nutch and Solr on a remote Ubuntu 14.04 Box. I have completed all the steps required, but I am supposed to access this URL to see Solr's results :

`http://localhost:8983/solr/#/demo`

How do I access this remotely? My server's IP can be taken as 10.200.300.400. I tried `http://10.200.300.400:8983/solr/#/demo`, but this does not work. (Preferably looking for a solution that does not require setting up Virtual Hosts)

Answer (score 6):

If the service is only bound to the loopback adapter, then it is only accessible from the local machine.

You could either change the listening interface of the server, or tunnel the port through SSH if you have SSH access.

Example of SSH port tunneling from the server to your local machine.

```
$ ssh -L 8983:localhost:8983 username@10.200.300.400
```

When the tunnel is open you should be able to access the service on your local machine using the same URL:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/#/demo
```

If you want a permanent solution for remote access to the service, you would have to change the listening interface or use a http server with reverse proxying capabilities (e.g. NginX or Apache Httpd).

Comment: this doesnt work for me when am trying to acess 8097 port of sagemaker from local machine